# Domain Events Using DDD/Repo/UoW/Serv

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm making a Rest Service for work, using:

- EntityFramework Core.
- Repository pattern
- UnitOfWork.
- Service pattern.
- Data Transfer Objects(Dto).
- Data Access Objects(Entity/Dao)

***Short about the project:***

- Large enterprice Rest API Service.
- Repositories's are responsible for CRUD and only CRUD.
- UnitOfWork contains every repository and get's the DbContext through dependency injection.
- My Dtos's are anemic models, i know this is considered bad practise by a number of people, but when making a Master API with a thousand entities each containing hundreds of columns, this is actually necessary. 
  So my Dto's actually just mirrors the Dao's(Not sensitive information though).
- Each entity has it's own repository.
- Each entity has it's own service class, which mainly uses the given entitiy's repository.
- Each entity has it's own controller and service class, each controller talks to the given service class.
- The service class only accepts Dto, each function converts from Dto to Dao, and then validates the entity, throwing an exception if the entity is not valid. When calling the approriate repository function and using UnitOfWork commit function to save the changes.
- Insert, Update And Delete by Navigation Properties is disabled/not allowed.
- This Database is in the Cloud and the company i'm working for has only been using edge databases, so we created a "SyncEngine" to synchronize data from the old database to the new cloud-based(this).

**Here comes the catch, where and how should i implement the events?**

Let's say i have a "User" entity which has a hundred fields required, and i have a factory method inside the entity, which takes hundred parameters length, this is not optimal at all, and then the event would have been triggered before even knowing it was added to the database? So i end up sending an email to the user, but the database is unavailable, so the user is not created, at all.

I know in DDD you should setup and aggregate and have the events inside the Entity etc, but then the events get triggered even if the write to DB was unsuccessful... and let's say i have a model with hundred required fields, it's not appropriate to have a factory method in the Dao/Entity class, which takes a hundred parameters?

Thanks in advance.
- Sincerely frustrated man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustrated man,

Generally, you will want to save your changes AND your events within the same database transaction. In this way, you guarantee that your events are only written when your changes are written.

Next, you should consider triggering email alerts only after the database has been written. Consider a distributed process where you pick up new events from the database and publish them to a queue. You can then have disparate processes that pick them up and process them (e.g. emailing the user).

Generally speaking, trying to do all of your work in one process with no transactional guarantees is a recipe for inconsistent state. Break your work into small units of work that you can guarantee and don't be afraid to offload the work to queues where you can similarly make guarantees about whether the work will be completed.

Regarding your other questions,

- You should ideally wrap your Root entities in Aggregates and maintain your logic there
- You should only have repositories for Root entities. They should load any dependent child entities. Child entities do not need to be loaded independently so they don't require repositories
- If you are dealing with hundreds of columns, can you vertically partition these tables and entities and turn them into many Roots? That is, do all of the columns get updated at the same time/use case? Having an entity of that size is inefficient from a read perspective, but also when writing if the fields are written from different use cases and will become a bottleneck under heavy writing scenarios.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will take a look into the distributed process. So you mean if i have an Order and OrderLine entity, the OrderLine operations should only be available through the OrderRepository? Because in the Rest Service i do not allow insertion from child objects, so if you send in an Order with a list of OrderLines this is not allowed by now

Comment: There is a difference between repository and operations. Operations are at the (Domain) service level. You load the Order from the repository and then you modify the OrderLines as needed. Then you save the Order back. The Order has the ability to apply business logic at that time.

Comment: If you are passing a whole Order DTO back to your service layer, then you should load that Order from the repository and then apply your changes as per the DTO. The diff logic is up to you.

Comment: Now i see what you mean, will try to assemble my test project. Thank you so much sir, helped me alot.

Comment: My pleasure! Feel free to ask any follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you! I have not yet started to write the test project, but i should also mention that this is the first Rest Service the company i am working for have, so we need to synchronize data from the old databases to the new one, you still think the Root Aggregate Entity is the way to go?

Comment: So if the "SyncEngine" will upload ten thousands OrderLines at ones, i will sort out the ones with same OrderId and call the OrderRepository? Instead of example: OrderLineRepository.AddRange?

Comment: @Mojo Correct. It's the only way you can ensure invariants. I know this sounds onerous, but it is the only way to ensure consistency within an Aggregate. It's a different question, however so post that as a separate question and I will answer there.

Comment: Thank you sir, created another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291032/aggregate-roots-ddd-uow-repo-service

Answer (score 1):

Most changes to a domain model should follow this sequence

1. Decide what to write down
2. Write it down
3. Tell the world about what you wrote down

1 `happens-before` 2.

2 `happens-before` 3.

Trying to make 2 and 3 concurrent opens up a world of expensive problems to solve.  So don't do that?

One alternative approach that fits some circumstance is to write down the event when you write the changes to the model (in step 2), and then use the list of stored events to decide what to broadcast (in step 3).

See Udi Dahan: [Reliable Messaging without Distributed Transactions](https://vimeo.com/channels/990578/111998645).

Comment: Thank you sir, really helped me out!